# Using the IDE to edit nested collections in Visual Studio C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface

I've been working on this for a few days and cant figure it out. Here's the situation. I have a CollectionBase that can hold many "layers" and in turn each layer can hold many objects. That part works fine in the code. The issue is when I go to edit the CollectionBase after placing the control in the form it will only allow me to get to the first layer.[image]

Now I've tried to make the Collection and Layers both List and CollectionBase. I've tried setting the attributes. Still no editing past the first layer.

this is where I'm at currently on the 2 as far as the declarations:

```
    [Serializable, Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
    Editor(typeof(CollectionBase), typeof(CollectionBase))]
    public class GameObjectCollection : CollectionBase, ICollection<GameObjectLayer>...

    [Serializable, Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always),
    Editor(typeof(CollectionBase), typeof(CollectionBase))]
    public class GameObjectLayer : CollectionBase, ICollection<GameObject>...

    [Serializable, Browsable(true), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Always)]
    public class GameObject : Object...
```

I know that it is probably something small and stupid. This is the first major custom control that I'm working on and I am just trying to get it to work properly for the end user.
Thank you in advanced for any help that you send my way.

Answer (score 0):

Workaround: I created a property field that allows me to edit the nested layers.

```
    public List<GameObjectLayer> Items...
```

The editor now sees the field and allows me to edit the nested list.